# How can i login ejabberd anonymously with given name?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I'm building a chat app, and i wanna manage my users in my own database. how can i use ejabberd to transmit my users's messages , who does not registered on ejabberd?

if it possible to login all the users anonymous, and still store their off-line messages?

if it not possible, what should i do ?